# eldoc error: (error Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size)

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, eldoc

I am editing `org-mode` files with a lot of source code blocks. These blocks contain my own pseudo code that looks like this:

```
(A) {B} (C) 
(D) {F} (Z)
```

When moving within these blocks there is a pause or delay of several seconds between movements. After that the error message `eldoc error: (error Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size)`is displayed. First I thought the recent 25.1.1 update of railwaycat's Emacs for Mac was the culprit. But after a downgrade to the latest 24 version, the issue is still there. I then tried to rollback any package updates (with `Spacemacs`). Alas, to no avail. What can I do?

Comment: The default value of `max-specpdl-size` was `1300`. I first set it to `2000` and then to `3000`. The issue remains.

Comment: I disabled `eldoc` globally using `(global-eldoc-mode -1)` which resolves the issue, but there is probably a more elegant solution required for users that rely on its functionality. Therefore I don't close the question yet.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and paste the backtrace here.  Or just report a bug with `M-x report-emacs-bug` and attach the backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion of @wasamasa:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Lisp nesting exceeds ‘max-lisp-eval-depth’")
  apply(provided-mode-derived-p org-mode org-mode)
  derived-mode-p(org-mode)
  org-get-limited-outline-regexp()
  org-element--current-element(358 element top-comment nil)
  org-element--parse-to(100)
  org-element-at-point()
  org-eldoc-get-src-lang()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
  eldoc--invoke-strategy()
  eldoc-print-current-symbol-info()
  org-eldoc-documentation-function()
  apply(org-eldoc-documentation-function nil)
  #f(advice-wrapper :before-until #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0x15735cd3e435>) org-eldoc-documentation-function)()
 
  .... ;; This goes on and on until we get:
  timer-event-handler([t 0 0 100000 t #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x15735d26f421>) nil idle 0])
```